# PHP5 Parsing string help for (part) noob

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have a unique item on an html page. I have been able to parse most of the items, since they are not using combined processed to parse one item.

I have a tricky item to parse:

- it is a list item, inside a DIV, which is unique (ld_sec_col)

- the UL class is not unique (ld_details_list)

- it is NOT a specific list item number (e.g. not the 3rd or 4th, that) always changes

- it IS found after unique text

- my problem is combining the techniques used to get it, without an error, and i am braindead.

```
Here is the snippet:
#####
   <div class="ld_sec_col">
    <ul class="ld_details_list">
    <li><span class="ld_lbl">Exterior:</span> Brick</li>
    <li><span class="ld_lbl">Living style:</span> Bungalow</li>
    <li><span class="ld_lbl">Property type:</span> Detached</li>
    <li><span class="ld_lbl">Sewer system:</span> Sewers</li>                   </ul>
    </div>
### End Snippet ###
```

So here I am trying to locate the unique text, (**Property type:**) and grab the text immediately following it:

I am obviously misusing FIND. And I am reduced to trial and error. But I would like to have this script done before Christmas. It is the last item....

```
### START PHP CODE ###

$tempproptype = trim($entry->find('.ld_sec_col', 0)->plaintext);
if(preg_match('/^Property type: (.*),/', $tempproptype, $matches))
$propertytype = $matches[1];

### ENDPHP CODE ###
```

Comment: I think you have an extra space and a comma in your regular expression where there is none to be found, should it not be `/^Property type:(.*)/` ? Also note, the result might also include html tags but give it a try

Comment: It's 2012. Use an XML parser.

Comment: You're already using some sort of HTML parser, so don't revert to parsing with regular expressions as well.  Keep using it to deal with the <span>.  What is the package you're using to parse the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the regex

```
'/^Property type: (.*),/'
```

with

```
'~Property type:</span>(.*)</li>~Ui'
```

Comment: The regex is solid with the HTML you posted, I think then $tempproptype must contain the wrong stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work I think:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="ld_sec_col">
<ul class="ld_details_list">
<li><span class="ld_lbl">Exterior:</span> Brick</li>
<li><span class="ld_lbl">Living style:</span> Bungalow</li>
<li><span class="ld_lbl">Property type:</span> Detached</li>
<li><span class="ld_lbl">Sewer system:</span> Sewers</li>                   </ul>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$propertytype = null;

if ($node = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='ld_details_list']/li[contains(.,'Property type:')]")->item(0)) {
    if(preg_match('/^Property type:(.*)$/', $node->nodeValue, $matches)) {
        $propertytype = trim($matches[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the look of this. I can't rewirte the script from scratch to use the loadhtml feature or query feature,  but tried replacing your containing terms. No success yet.

Comment: I think we're all assuming `$tempproptype` contains the snippet, however if that's the case both Wolfgang's regex and this would work. You don't need to rewrite everything to try out the XPath method, just replace `$html` with your `$tempproptype`… and if it fails, post the result of a var_dump($tempproptype) so we can see what the variable actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

Try preg_match('/Property type:</span>([A-z]*)/', $tempproptype, $matches)

Comment: I did try this, thank you for your idea - it did  not produce any content.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up going with:

```
$subpropertytypehtml = $html->find('.ld_details_list', 1)->find('li');          
        for($i=0;$i<count($subpropertytypehtml)-1;$i++)
        {
            if(preg_match('/Property type:/', $subpropertytypehtml[$i], $matches))
            {
                $subproptypehtml = trim($html->find('.ld_details_list', 1)->find('li', $i)->plaintext);
                $expsubproptypehtml=explode('Property type:',$subproptypehtml);
                $subpropertytype=$expsubproptypehtml[1];
                break;
            }               
        }
```